# How are the transactions stored on disk?

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, full-node

I'm trying to get a better understanding of how Bitcoin works.

I understand that a full node can store the entire Blockchain on their machine. If they choose not to prune, there should be a huge file containing all transactions, right?

If so, is it possible to inspect this file? I think this would really help me grasp the concept.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

How it's stored depends on each implementation. Bitcoin Core creates a series of files named `blockXXXXXX.dat`, where XXXXXX is a sequence number that ever increases, these files are inside the `.bitcoin/blocks` folder. These files are 128 MiB-long and contains the serialized blocks (almost the same way you send them to others over the network). You can inspect it, just open one of these files and will find block data in there.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I'm not on the network yet. Could you kindly provide a screenshot for me if it's not a big effort?